# Setup CNAME to force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites

I've been spinning my wheels on this for weeks and I know others have asked this question but I can't seem to find enough detail to relate what others are doing to what I'm doing.  And it doesn't help that the implementation guide is not in sync with Help & Training.

So what i've done so far in prod:

1. Under Develop->Sites, Created force.com domain: somedomain.force.com
2. Created a site under this domain to render a VF page: somedomain.force.com/test
3. 'Requires Secure Connections (HTTPS) is checked (true), login not allowed, and IP ranges are set
4. CNAME was registered to point to somedomain.force.com

When i enter my custom domain (somedomain.com) i get error:
**"Invalid URL
The requested URL "/", is invalid.
Reference #9.57e64217.1418350240.4c72196"**

I've read that the CNAME should point to my force.com domain with 18 digit org id and live.siteforce.com but if I run dig or nslookup, that name does not resolve to an IP.  Should it resolve to an IP address?

I've also read that I should create a domain in Salesforce under Domain Management and point it to my site, then have CNAME point to that domain, but i'm confused.  I already created a domain (somedomain.force.com) prior to creating the site.  So do I create a new domain and point it to the site that I created under somedomain.force.com?  If yes, then do I point the CNAME to the new domain?  And if I do have to create a new domain should it follow the format of .<18 digit org id>.live.siteforce.com?

Or is my original setup fine and the problem has more to do with the setting for 'Require Secure Connection (HTTPS)'?

Comment: Important to note that force.com sites and siteforce are two very, very different things. Anything siteforce-related you've read should be ignored if you're using a force.com site as described.

Comment: thank you! that clears up a lot.  I thought something magical would happen on the DNS side, but glad to know i can ignore anything siteforce related

Answer (score 1):

In step -4 your CNAME should be registered to point to something like this (not the salesforce subdomain)

https://customdoamin.com.yourOrgId.live.siteforce.com . You can find this URL under setup-domains-domain management-Add a doamin

Comment: Thank you for that.  I also found this helpful https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205653&language=en_US